# In Perl/Moose, can I have two attributes with mutually-dependent defaults?

Tags: perl, attributes, moose

Can I do this in Moose?

```
package SomeClass;
use Moose;

has start => (
    isa => 'Int',
    is => 'ro',
    lazy => 1,
    default => sub { $_[0]->end },
);

has end => (
    isa => 'Int',
    is => 'ro',
    lazy => 1,
    default => sub { $_[0]->start },
);

...
```

In other words, I want two attributes called "start" and "end", and if only one of them is specified, I want the other one to be set to the same thing. Not specifying either one is an error.

Does this mutually-dependent setup work?

Comment: This does not make failure to specify either an error, but otherwise should work.  I'd suspect that failure to specify either and then accessing one of them is going to cause infinite recursion.  But that should be easy to verify - just test it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, *if* you remove the possibility of infinite recursion by verifying that at least one of these values is specified:

```
has start => (
    ...
    predicate => 'has_start',
);

has end => (
    ...
    predicate => 'has_end',
);

sub BUILD
{
    my $self = shift;

    die "Need to specify at least one of 'start', 'end'!" if not $self->has_start and not $self->has_end;
}
```

Alternatively, you could delay the check to the default subs:

```
has start => (
    ...
    predicate => 'has_start',
    default => sub {
        my $self = shift;
        die "Need to specify at least one of 'start', 'end'!" if not $self->has_end;
        $self->end;
    },
);

has end => (
    ...
    predicate => 'has_end',
    default => sub {
        my $self = shift;
        die "Need to specify at least one of 'start', 'end'!" if not $self->has_start;
        $self->start;
    },
);
```

Comment: Does that first one actually work? I thought BUILD got called after the attributes had been set up and defaults applied where necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I'd take advantage of laziness to ensure that I didn't get caught in an infinite recursion:

```
has start => (
  is => 'ro',
  isa => 'Int',
  lazy => 1,
  default => sub { shift->end },
  predicate => 'has_start',
);

has end => (
  is => 'ro',
  isa => 'Int',
  lazy => 1,
  default => sub { shift->start },
  predicate => 'has_end',
);

sub BUILD {
  my $self = shift;

  die "Need to specify at least one of 'start', 'end'!" 
    unless $self->has_start || $self->has_end;
}
```